# Minting candy machine v3 umi getting incorrect account owner error using express js endpoint

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, metaplex, nft, candy-machine-v3

I am using the below in an endpoint to create a candy machine. Currently getting an incorrect account owner following the guide provided here https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/managing-candy-machines , when I use the generatesigner to use as a keypair it says it needs sol to mint, but the guides use this, opposed to a wallet keypair which I switched out in my example. Thanks for any help. [image]

```
  
  
    try {
      let QUICKNODE_RPC = "https://api.devnet.solana.com"
  
      const umi = createUmi(QUICKNODE_RPC).use(mplCandyMachine()).use(mplTokenMetadata());
      const numberOfItems = 12;
      // console.log("umi", umi)
  
      // Create the Collection NFT.
  
      const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secret));
      const umiSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, keypair);
      umi.use(signerIdentity(umiSigner));
  
  
  
      const collectionMint = generateSigner(umi);

      await createNft(umi, {
        mint: collectionMint,
        authority: umiSigner,
        name: "Rowdy Knights Club",
        uri: "assets/collection.json",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(9.99, 2), // 9.99%
        isCollection: true,
      }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
  
  
      // Create the Candy Machine.
      const candyMachineKeypair = generateSigner(umi);
  
      const instruction = await create(umi, {
        candyMachine: candyMachineKeypair,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: umi.identity,
        collectionMint: collectionMint.publicKey,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.ProgrammableNonFungible,
        itemsAvailable: 3,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(10, 2),
        creators: [
          {
            address: umi.identity.publicKey,
            verified: true,
            percentageShare: 100,
          },
        ],
        symbol: 'Rowdy',
        configLineSettings: some({
          prefixName: '',
          nameLength: 32,
          prefixUri: '',
          uriLength: 200,
          isSequential: false,
        }),
      });
  
  
      await transactionBuilder().add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 800_000 })).add(instruction).sendAndConfirm(umi);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

hey I was also facing the same issue, check the below code

```
const { createUmi } = require("@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults");
const {
  mplCandyMachine,
  create,
  getMplCandyGuardErrorFromCode,
} = require("@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine");
const {
  createNft,
  TokenStandard,
} = require("@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata");
const {
  generateSigner,
  percentAmount,
  keypairIdentity,
  some,
} = require("@metaplex-foundation/umi");
const bs58 = require("bs58");

const umi = createUmi(
  "https://api.devnet.solana.com",
).use(mplCandyMachine());

const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(
  bs58.decode(
    "YOUR PRIVATE KEY"
  )
);
// const keypairSigner
// Use the RPC endpoint of your choice.

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));

const getFeeForMessage = async (message) => {
  let body = JSON.stringify({
    id: 1,
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    method: "getFeeForMessage",
    params: [
      message,
      {
        commitment: "processed",
      },
    ],
  });

  let res = await fetch(
    "rpc",
    {
      method: "POST",
      body,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  console.log(res.json().then((data) => console.log(data)));
};

async function create_cm() {
  const collectionUpdateAuthority = generateSigner(umi);
  const collectionMint = generateSigner(umi);

  let collection = await createNft(umi, {
    mint: collectionMint,
    authority: collectionUpdateAuthority,
    name: "My Collection NFT",
    uri: "https://example.com/path/to/some/json/metadata.json",
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(9.99, 2), // 9.99%
    isCollection: true,
  }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

  const candyMachine = generateSigner(umi);

  console.log("Accounts")
  console.log(collectionMint.publicKey);
  console.log(collectionUpdateAuthority.publicKey);
  console.log(candyMachine.publicKey);
   

  let nft = await create(umi, {
    candyMachine,
    collectionMint: collectionMint.publicKey,
    collectionUpdateAuthority,
    tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(9.99, 2), // 9.99%
    itemsAvailable: 100,
    creators: [
      {
        address: umi.identity.publicKey,
        verified: true,
        percentageShare: 100,
      },
    ],
    configLineSettings: some({
      prefixName: "",
      nameLength: 32,
      prefixUri: "",
      uriLength: 200,
      isSequential: true,
    }),
  });

  let tx = await nft.buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi, {
    commitment: "finalized",
  });

  console.log(tx.message);

  console.log(await nft.sendAndConfirm(umi));
}

create_cm();
```

The above code is working- also make sure your wallet has enough SOL for the transaction - you can get some devnet sol from faucet.solana.com

Comment: This only worked after I changed `const collectionUpdateAuthority = generateSigner(umi);` to `const collectionUpdateAuthority = keypairSigner.publicKey;` where `const keypairSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, keypair);`